# Communicating with DB through SSH in GWT app (using RPC)

Tags: gwt, servlets, ssh, rpc, jsch

I am trying to write a GWT back-end using the RPC model for java servlets.
Is it possible to ssh tunnel within an RPC in order to communicate with a remote sql database?

The code I try to execute is below, using Jsch. The error occurs on "session.connect();"

```
String host="xxxxx.xxx.edu";

String user="username";
String password="password";

Session session= null;
try{
            //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
}
```

The runtime error I get on the 'session.connect()' line is as follows: (scroll right to see whole error)

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission xxxxx.xxx.edu resolve)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:341)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:194)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
at com.front.server.GameServiceImpl.createGame(GameServiceImpl.java:39)
```

The frustrating part about this is that I copied/pasted the exact same code into a simple java program and it works. So I know the code is correct; obviously the jetty server which GWT creates for local testing has a problem executing the code. What else can I do / what should I be doing in this situation with GWT? Shouldn't the back-end of a GWT application have the capacity to ssh??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try running your gwt app with a different web container (Tomcat, JBoss). You can still make use of debugging functionality by running the hosted mode with the -noserver flag.
See [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s)